# GitHub Actions: Can I use a variable for the Environment field of a job?

Tags: variables, github, github-actions, environment

I've tested this but I'd like to believe I'm just missing something. Can I use an environment variable in the Environment field?

```yaml
name: workflow_name
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - workflowBranch

env:
  subscriptionId: <subscriptionId>
  resourceGroupName: <resourceGroupName>
  armParameterFile: <armParameterFile>
  
jobs: 
  validate_and_generate:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Upload Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ${{ env.armParameterFile }}
        path: ${{ env.armParameterFile }}
  deploy:
    needs: validate_and_generate
    environment: SBX # <-- Can I use a variable here?
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ env.armParameterFile }}
          path: ${{ env.armParameterFile }}
```

This is the line in question:

> environment: SBX # <-- Can I use a variable here?